# Video: 1970 911T starts for the first time in 15 years - What next?

Tags: maintenance, restoration, porsche, 911

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QQzbEQTWAo&sns=em

My brothers and I have been working on this car since last fall.  So far we've done the following:

- Had the zenith carbs rebuilt and bench synchronized
- Did a compression test - they were all around 112psi
- Changed the oil (actually just replaced all the oil that had leaked out of it).
- Changed the points
- Checked static ignition timing

We still have the following immediate tasks on our plate:

- Adjust the valves - We think that's what is causing the wicked backfires... Any input is appreciated.
- Replace a leaking oil pressure sending unit
- Fix an oil leak around the oil tank (see around 13 seconds in the video)
- Rebuild all 4 brake calipers

Anything jump out at you from the video might be higher on our priority list?  We hope to have it in driveable condition by the end of the summer.

Wish us luck :)

...Peter

Answer (score 4):

If you planned on driving this more than once, I would replace all fluids in the car (oil, transmission/clutch, brake, coolant, power steering, etc.)  I would then look over all rubber belts and tubes to make sure they are all still in decent condition, if not, replace.  Vacuum lines need to be in decent shape also.

Once you know your brake system is in working and safe order, I would then look at the tires and make sure they are in good shape (no cracks, bulges, bubbles, exposed support wires, etc.)  Where was this car stored over the 15 years?  If it was outside, I would consider replacing the tires before going very far in it.  Might want to replace that old spare while your at it.  Just because it has decent tread doesn't mean it is a good tire to use.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  The only thing is... I can't find the coolant overflow tank ;)

Answer (score 3):

Let me also suggest that the backfire issue is related to ignition, not the valves. Check your timing, which you said you did statically, and also check to be sure the plug wires are in the proper place on the distributor. Easy to mess that up and it will cause a major odd firing of the engine.
the above comments about fluids and tires is also on the money, but it is not relevant if they were outside or in. after 6 years any tire should be replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the input... We'll drag out a timing light this weekend and see if we're on.  We also got some great startup advice from the pelican auto parts forums... check it out: http://forums.pelicanparts.com/porsche-911-technical-forum/598102-video-1970-911t-starts-first-time-15-years.html

Comment: Also take a look at the forums at rennlist.org